# Finding median from PDF and multiple cases

Tags: statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions, median

> The random variable $X$ has the probability density function given by:
> $$
>   f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{2x}{3},  & 0 \le x \le 1 \\
> \frac{2}{3}, & 1 \lt x \le 2 \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Find the median of $X$.

I know that the CDF is needed to calculate the median, which I calculated as follows:

$$
  F(X) =
\begin{cases}
0, & x \lt 0 \\
\frac{x^2}{3},  & 0 \le x \le 1 \\
\frac{2x}{3}, & 1 \lt x \le 2 \\
1, & x \gt 2
\end{cases}
$$

Since $\int{\frac{2x}{3}} = \frac{x_0^2}{3}$ and $\int{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{2x_0}{3}$. I then thought that I could find the median as follows:

$$
\frac{m^2}{3} + \frac{2m}{3} = 0.5 \\
2m^2 + 4m - 3 = 0 \\
m = \frac{-2+\sqrt10}{2}
$$

Ignoring the `-` value because it falls outside the range of interest.  The correct answer is $1.25$ and I'm a bit confused on how to find it. Could somebody explain where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking for the value $m$ which fulfill the equation $F_X(m)=0.5$. If you have a pdf with intervals you start to prove if the first interval is larger or equal to 0.5.

$\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{3} \, dx =\frac13<0.5$

We need the second interval of the cdf. The cdf of the second interval is

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{3} \, dx+\int_1^m \frac{2}{3} \, dx=0.5$$

So you have really to calculate both integrals including the bounds:

$$\left[\frac{x^2}{3} \right]_0^1+\left[\frac{2x}{3} \right]_1^m=0.5$$

$$\frac{1}{3} +\frac{2m}{3}-\frac{2}{3}=0.5$$

All it is left is to solve the equation for $m$. The left hand side is the cdf of the second interval: $\frac{2x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}$. If we insert the upper bound we obtain  $\frac{2\cdot 2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4-1}3=1$. This is the result we expect.

Comment: Thank you, really clear explanation